# Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open() in c

Tags: php, codeigniter

i got this error and daunt know where i went wrong i am new to codeigniter so i am sure its something stupid can anyone figure this out tnx in advance.

create_view.php

```
     <body>
        <?php echo form_open('create'); ?>
        <ul id="accordion">
 <li>
   <a>Survey Creation</a>
     <ul id="survay">  
       <li>Enter a question:<?php echo form_input('Question')?></li>
       <li>Answer A: <?php echo form_input('qA' );?></li>
       <li>Answer B: <?php echo form_input('qB' );?></li>
       <li>Answer C: <?php echo form_input('qC' );?></li>
       <li><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Set This Question' );?></li>
      </ul>  
  </li>
```

create.php

```
 <?php

class Create extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){

        $this->load->view('create_view');
    }
    // insert data
    function create1()
    {   
     $data = array(
         'Question' => $this->input->post('Question'),
         'qA' => $this->input->post('qA'),
         'qB' => $this->input->post('qB'),
         'qC' => $this->input->post('qC'),


         );


          $this->create_model->add_record($data);
          $this->home();

    }



 }

?>
```

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to load the [form helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html). Use the `application/config/autoload.php` or add the following line into your controller before loading the view:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Answer (score 14):

You may also load this helpers on all controllers.
Go your config folder and open autoload.php in any editor and then load required helper as following :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');
```

Answer (score 4):

Load your CI helper in your controller 
    $this->load->helper('form');

```
class Create extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){

        $this->load->view('create_view');
        $this->load->helper('form');
```

or make auto load helpers on all contollers. Open application/config/autoload.php

```
        $autoload['helpers'] = array('form','myhelper');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load Helper 'Form' before using this function.
Add this line:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have following line above view called in controller:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation'); //make sure to have it, before view call 

$this->load->view('profile');
```